# Disassociating yourself from a question

Tags: feature-request

I recently asked a question containing personal matters about my situation. This question received a bunch of unexpected attention and got on the `Hot Network Questions` list. It wasn't smart of me (You could say pretty stupid) to use my main account with my real name and logo.

I have used the `contact us` page to send a mail to disassociate myself from said question, but shouldn't there be an easier way to do this? Or is just another case of it being 'my fault and I should own up to it'?

I just wondered if it would be better/easier to include such a feature. I'm aware it isn't fair to be able to delete the question, but I think StackExchange could have a feature where you can post something anonymously without having to create a second account.

Comment: Take it as a learning experience, never post anything negative on the internet with your real name and photo. You never know when and how it will come back to bite you in the posterior. As an additional "safety net", I don't use my real name and photo here, and I take care not to login from office devices. That saves me the headache of constant self-censoring.

Comment: You're right, I immediately changed my name/profile picture. I'll just chalk this up to me being careless. Thank you for your help Monica!

Comment: Don't be ashamed to be you, we all got to be someone.

Answer (score 7):

Disassociation requires human intervention, and that's a good thing.  If somebody is posting and then wanting to disassociate a lot of stuff, we probably want to talk with that person about better ways to use the site.  Also, if somebody is behaving badly (and thus attracting flags), we want to see that activity in context (what else has this person posted?).  I hope you can see how that would be especially important with trolls and spammers.

Disassociation should therefore not be self-serve.  Yes, sometimes you goof and it's very frustrating to have to wait; I get that.  I wish I had a better answer for you, like some sort of "soft disassociation" that breaks the public link while still preserving it for moderators, but we don't have anything like that.  Moderators can't even do the disassociation that we do have; that requires an SE employee.  So we'll forward flags, but using the "contact us" form is the fastest way and, unfortunately, that could take some time.

I escalated this request for you and a CM has just disassociated the post.

Comment: But there must be a better way to do this, right? I'm fully aware I'm 100% at fault here, but I just hoped there would be a better way to do this. I understand it can never be self-serve, like you pointed out. But is there no way to 'temporarily disassociate' so no one can see until a moderator approves or rejects? Take my question for example, I wanted to hide it when it got ~200 views, it currently resides at ~2150. All I can do is hope no one from my company saw it...

Comment: I escalated your request.  Done now.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, special requests like that are made by flagging the question for moderator attention. Select the "Other" option and explain the situation and a moderator will address it and if applicable they will either take care of it or escalate it to a SE employee if necessary/required. If they can't handle it or have reasons not to, they'll explain that too.

Comment: Moderators can't actually disassociate posts, so all we can do is forward that request to SE to handle.  That works, but you might as well skip the middleman in case the middleman is busy and doesn't notice the flag right away.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I tend to have a gross mistrust of "contact us" in general and see it as a a redirect to /dev/null which is why I suggested moderation. I figure you guys at least know where to send something.